# Perl : How to replace a _[0-9] with a comma in perl or any language

Tags: regex, linux, perl

I have a file with the following pattern
'21pro_ABCD_EDG_10800_48052_2  0.0'

How do i replace the _[0-9] with a ,(comma)
so that i can get the output as

21pro_ABCD_EDG,10800,48052,2,  0.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace the `_[0-9]` with a `,` you can do [this](http://codepad.org/fTkN0hM9):

```
$s =~ s/_([0-9])/,$1/g 

#the same without capturing groups
$s =~ s/_(?=[0-9])/,/g;
```

---

**Edit:**
To get the extra comma after the `2` you can do this:

```
#This puts a , before all whitespace.
$s =~ s/_(?=[0-9])|(?=\s)/,/g;

#This one puts a , between [0-9] and any whitespace
$s =~ s/_(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=\s)/,/g;
```

Comment: oops the output is 21pro_ABCD_EDG,10800,48052,2 0.0 i need a ',' after the last '2' and before the 0.0 Can you help me with that

Comment: I've edited my answer to solve this problem. Let me know if there are any other rules that this doesn't cover.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer. It helps your and my reputation. Thanks, j

Answer (score 1):

The sed approach would be something like the following:

```
rupert@hake:~ echo '21pro_ABCD_EDG_10800_48052_2 0.0' | sed 's/_\([0-9]\)/,\1/g'
21pro_ABCD_EDG,10800,48052,2 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the expression mentioned by jacob, here is the code snippet to perform the substitution for a large file

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
open (MYFILE, 'test');
while (<MYFILE>) {
    chomp;
    $s=$_;
    $s =~ s/_(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=\s)/,/g;
    $s =~ s/\s//g;
    print "$s\n";
}
```

close (MYFILE);